# Daemon threads in ForkJoinPool

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon, java.util.concurrent, fork-join

According to Java Doc 7:

> Because ForkJoinPool uses threads in daemon mode, there is typically
>   no need to explicitly shut down such a pool upon program exit

Are there no other advantages? 
Is a daemon thread only different from a normal thread in "alive until the system is alive"? 
Does it only mean I don´t have to care about shutting down the ForkJoinPool?

Can someone clear me up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daemon has very little affect in Java. If you don't shut down the pool, then you will not recover all the memory it uses. That includes the threads.